# Overcoming Exclude List Limit Size

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to make a query using Django's Exclude() and passing to it a list, as in:

`(...).exclude(id__in=list(top_vip_deals_filter))`

The problem is that, apparently, there is a Limit -- depending on your database --on the size of the list being passed.

Is this correct?
If so, How to overcome this?
If not, is there some explanation to the fact that queries silently fail when the list size is big?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the top_vip_deals_filter comes from the database, you can set an extra where in the query:

```
(...).extra(where=['model.id not in select blah blah'])
```

(put your lowercase model name instead of `model`.)

You can do better if the data model allows you to. If you can do it in SQL, you probably can do it in django.